# Borda na folha inteira usando mPDF

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Estou tentando gerar meu pdf com este layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Header e o Footer ja estão corretos, só não consigo achar uma solução para desenhar essa borda em torno da página inteira. Se alguém tiver alguma dica agradeço desde já.

Comment: Ele aceita CSS? Já tentou colocar uma borda no body?

Comment: @MBoss pode se faz favor colocar o código que gera o PDF. Assim Podemos ajudar melhor.